# Redux state is updated but not the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

I am facing problem in updating/re-rendering component after store and state updation.

**1-** On page load a store is created with empty initial state so all components are rendered with empty

```
 store = createStore(Reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware, thunk), extension));
```

**2-** Then data from API is taken and action is dispatched with that data.

```
 axios.get(url).then(res => {
  store.dispatch(getFromServer(res.data));
 })
```

**3-** state is an object here and keys of objects are reducers and components and reducers are combined through [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers).so when getFromServer action is dispatched it is listened in all reducers.and updates state object in respective reducer.Example reducer is as follows.

```
  import update from 'immutability-helper';
  import * as types from '../actions/constants';
  const initialState = {};
  export default (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case types.GET_FROM_SERVER:
        return update(state,{
            $set:action.schema.database
        })
    case types.SAVE_NAME:
        return { name: action.name };
    default:
        return state;
  }
 };
```

Now i can see that at first my component has empty state and then state is updated correctly.component code is as follows:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { observable } from 'mobx';
 import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
 import Table from '../containers/Table';
 @observer class Tables extends Component {'
   props: Props
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tables : { }  }
}
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
        tables : this.props.tables
    })
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        tables : this.props.tables
    })
}   

render() {
    var {tables} = this.props;
    console.log(tables);
    return (
        <div className='table-wrapper'>
            { tables.map((table) => (
                <div key={ table.id }>{
                <Table
                    key={ table.id }
                    data={ table }                        
                />)</div>
            ))}                
        </div>
    );
}
}

type Props = {
  tables: Array<TableType>    
};

export default Tables;
```

i can see state change in browser console here.

[image]

prev state and next state is showing the state updation.

Also render method showing that this.props.data is updating.but still view is not updated here.

Am i doing wrong while state updation as mentioned [Here](https://redux.js.org/troubleshooting)?

Comment: Can you add the code of the component that is not being updated?

Comment: Your component is probably not listening for state changes

Comment: I have updated my question and added component.u can see console.log(tables) there.this is showing that on state change component is called and tables data is updated but component is nt re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook for catching the moment of updating the component from props:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        tables : this.props.tables
    })
}
```

But, I'm pretty sure that you wanted to update the state with new props

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  this.setState({
     tables : nextProps.tables
  })
}
```

Comment: i was bashing my head in this issue for 2 days.thanx buddy.this is useful.i thought it must an immutability issue but i wsnt.thanx.

Comment: Sure:) Also just learning React. After Vue.js it seems way more complex.

Comment: @N.A, could you approve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You extract `tables` from `this.props`, extract it from `this.state` so it will update at each render.

```
render() {
  const {tables} = this.state;
```

Another thing, you `map()` tables, so I assume it's an Array. So you should initialize it with an array instead of an object:

From:

```
this.state = { tables : { }  }
```

To:

```
this.state = { tables : [ ]  }
```

Comment: Aaaaand what @Yevhenii Herasymchuk just said.

Comment: this.state is not showing updation but this.prop is showing